# Mixing ASP.NET Core (full .net framework) with older .Net Framework 2.0 code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Core app, targeting the full framework. I need to reference some .NET framework 2.0 dll but get following error:

Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

I could add the following to the app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/>
</startup>
```

but the project does not have an app.config file. Should I add the app.config, or can this be done by configuring the host / app in code?